# Not loading my application on blackberry 9220 simualotr

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Does anyone know this error below its not loading my application on blackberry 7.1(9220) simulator.

[image]

Comment: its working in any other simulators ?

Comment: ya its working on my blackberry 8900 which is version BlackBerry 5.0

Comment: when you load the simulator, its hangs ?

Comment: yes while i am loading my project on simulator 7.1 it hangs.

Comment: i faced same problem. But when i revert back to java 7 to 6, the problem solved.